# USB 3.1 Gen II - if there are two attached Gen I devices, will it allocate 5Gbps to each?

Tags: hardware, usb

Most USB PCIe add-on cards are single chipset and the ports share the available bandwidth.

Theoretically, if I have two USB 3.1 Gen I devices that each can saturate the 5Gbps bandwidth, attaching them to a USB 3.1 Gen I add-on card will limit each to 2.5Gbps.

Will attaching two Gen I devices to a Gen II add-on card allow each to run at its full 5Gbps, being Gen II is 10Gbps?

Comment: I heard people claim *bandwidth sharing* works for them reliably with certain combinations of host, devices, drivers & cables, but I'll believe it when I see it. Strong recommendation to not depend on it in a production setting.

Comment: @anx Update that bandwidth sharing definitely doesn't work under VMWare PCI passthrough